# Blazor Server get SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, blazor

I have a new Blazor Server App, basic counter app.  Running on my localhost.  I would like to create a .razor page that pulls data from a SharePoint list.  What is the best way to do this.  I briefly tried to use PnP.Core but hit permission issues, as I think the app is running locally.  I tried Graph but was a bit unsure.  I have a SP Client ID and Secret, provided by my IT department

Any idea what the easyiest way to do this is.

TIA